# How to save a dictionary with a size of 9 Gb in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 9 Gb size in the memory(My total memory is 64Gb). I tried both `pickle` and `joblib` to store the dictionary, however, the memory blows up when I tried to do that. I just wonder how to solve this?

Comment: What data type(s) are in the dictionary (numbers, strings, lists or more complicated)?

Comment: It is something like this `adict[key1][key2] = [80, 100]`

Comment: This looks like a dictionary with dictionaries as value which in turn have lists of `int`s as values, right? What type can be `key1` and `key2`?

Comment: `key1` and `key2` is like ids. Pretty long string though. like : `t_13d34e4b-dc9b-4535-963d-419afa8332ec`

Comment: How about using a database (SQLite or something bigger) for that?

Comment: There are also some other solutions listed here that you might find helpful: https://pythonspot.com/save-a-dictionary-to-a-file/